# Name output feature classes with feature names with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, clip, loop, layer-name, output

I would like to have my output feature classes take on the name of the input features list that I am looping through. Example output FEMA_Clip_09302022

The code below is currently creating output features with the same names as the fc's that I am looping through. I have been trying to get my output features to export as so FEMA_Clip_"whatever todays date is". With the code below, they are exporting as FEMA.shp, etc, etc.

```
    #Import mod
    import arcpy
    import os
    import datetime

    #Set Workspace
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\Batch\SFWMD"
    
    #Variables
    outputFolder = r"X:\Ben\GIS\Shapefile\Test Files"
    clip_feat =  r"E:\Batch\SFWMD\District.shp"
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    currentDate = str(now.month) + str(now.day) + str(now.year)
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    #Loop
    - for fc in fcList
         currentDate = str(now.month) + str(now.day) + str(now.year)
         outputName = "{}_Clip.shp".format(fc)
         outputPath = os.path.join(outputFolder, outputName + currentDate)
         arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clip_feat, outputPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the currentDate after the .shp file extension.
Change your loop to something similar to this:

```
for fc in fcList
   currentDate = str(now.month) + str(now.day) + str(now.year)
   outputName = "{0}_Clip_{1}.shp".format(fc, currentDate )
   outputPath = os.path.join(outputFolder, outputName)
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for the response. I see that this correction is attempting to pass the variables fc and currentDate from the format command, but for some reason the output .shp files are still taking on the same names as the input .shp files. I have tried tooling around with different variations of your response and still cannot seem to get it to export with the desired format. Do you have any additional input on this? I am only three weeks in to learning Python so the placement of certain commands within any code is still a work in progress. Any and all insight is much appreciated!